# unsure about database logic for multiple items

Tags: php, mysql, database, logic

I am trying to get my head around an issue relating to database logic.

I have a system that is to allow the user to create an event, performances and multiple different ticket types for a given event.  These will then be added to the database with prices relating to the ticket types for a given event (the ticket types can be reused for other events and there is no set number of types for each event) and then a customer will go onto the site, select one of the events, performances and will then have listed for them to choose from the different ticket types with prices.

At this point I have a table for events which is using a series to store the ticket ids which are stored in a separate table and yet another table which stores the prices.  The use of the series is ridiculous as it tends to crap out on me and either fails to work (as mysql doesn't handle the code properly) or it is incredibly limiting on what can be done with the info  Has anyone any better idea how I might achieve this result?

example of an event:

event name: 'event 1'

performance: '23/03/13 (12:30)'

ticket types:  Adult (€20), Student (€15), Special (€10), etc

the person setting up the event can create any ticket types they want or use existing ones in the system and just have a price set for this particular event.

Comment: Could you possibly add an example of an event, with its performances and tickets? It will make it a lot easier to understand what you want.

Comment: Better yet, explain why you think it's ridiculous, so far it seems like you're on the right track.  I would have tables for events, tickets, and a table that represents the many-to-many relationship you described for events and ticket types.

Comment: The use of the series is ridiculous as it tends to crap out on me and either fails to work (as mysql doesn't handle the code properly) or it is incredibly limiting on what can be done with the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I believe what you are doing is most likely the best way to do it.

A user can create multiple events, each of which can have a variety of tickets. Tickets are not specific to an event (can be used on multiple events), and thus the price can not be stored with the ticket information.

Therefore, what you want to do is have these tables:

*events* - Stores information on the event
*tickets* - Stores information on the ticket
*events_tickets* - a join table for *events* and *tickets* (As it is a many to many relationship)

The events_tickets table would have columns like so:
*primary id*, event_id (Foreign Key), ticket_id (Foreign Key), price

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you're right, but how do I go about using this info?  The way I see it I will have to reference the tickets price table based on the event id which is fine.  but for each ticket that is returned I will need to then reference the tickets and event tables to get the names of them and other info.  What way should this be done or am I missing something?

Comment: The events_tickets table is a many-to-many join table. It has the ID of the event AND the ticket. This way you can get the info from the tickets table using that ticket ID, or the info from the events table using the event_id column. The price is stored in the join table as it is specific to that relationship between the ticket and event. Is that what you're trying clarify?

Comment: Not quite but the mention of a many-to-many table I think nailed it.  I need to do a bit of reading as never set up or used a many-to-many junction table before.

Comment: One to many relationships store the foreign within one of the tables (for example, if an event can have many tickets, but a ticket can only have one event, the event_id would be stored in the tickets table). With many to many relationships, a join table is necessary to relate the data together. :-) Hopefully that increases your understanding of them.

Comment: yes, and confuses the hell out of me at the same time.  Just need to find a good doc relating to it and I'm sure I'll figure it all out.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Even though this is mainly about the DataMapper extension for CodeIgniter, the logic is sound about relationships. http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/relationtypes.html

Answer (score 0):

table Event: Id_Event, Ds_Event, Dt_Event, Id_Venue

table Ticket_Type: Id_Ticket_Type, Ds_Ticket_Type, Ic_Ticket_Type_Is_Custom (boolean)

table Event_Ticket_Type_Price: Id_Event, Id_Ticket_Type, Nr_Ticket_Price

table Venue: Id_Venue, Ds_Venue, Ds_Venue_Address